# how to pass params in remotefunction

Tags: javascript, grails

I have a javascript function with remotefunction,,, in that remotefunction i want to pass map has parameter and i want to use that map variable in controller action,, i don't know how to pass that in params of ramotefunction and to use it in that particular controller action...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 alert("checking for checkbox");
 var countryId = document.getElementById("countryId").value;
    jQuery('#groupdelete').on('click', function(){
        var names = {};
        alert("*********");
        jQuery('input:checked').each(function() {
            alert(jQuery(this).attr("id"));
            if(jQuery(this).attr("id")) {
            var id=jQuery(this).attr("id")
            var costId = "c"+id
            var ntb = document.getElementById(costId).value;
            alert(ntb);
            names[id] = ntb;
            }   
        });
        alert(names[1]);
    })


    ${remoteFunction(action:'addLabServiceToCountry', controller:'country', params:'\'names=\'+names')}
```

})

```
params:'\'names=\'+names' which is not working properly, how to pass map variable in params of remotefunction and in contoller action how to access that.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
${remoteFunction({action: "addLabServiceToCountry", controller: "country", params: names});
```

Then in `remoteFunction()` you need to iterate through `params` to get all mapped names.

Or you can convert `names` to a string:

```
var namesStr = names.join(',');
```

and then pass the string:

```
${remoteFunction({... , params: namesStr});
```